# MediaCodec: How to test/play the output of Encoder.?

Tags: android, video, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-mediacodec

I'm new to android development. I'm trying to write a video compressor application for android phones that runs on jellybean version. I'm using MediaCodec API.

The following is the initial setup that I made to start the decoder & encoder. I did encoding & decoding as per the documentation. But the output I'm getting is not playable by simply double clicking on it. Could anyone suggest me a way to check the output to see whether it worked or not.?

```
// Prepare and start Decoder.
MediaCodec mediaDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(inputFileMIME /* got from input file using MediaMetadataRetriever */);
mediaDecoder.configure(mediaFormatForDecoder /* got from input file using MediaMetadataRetriever */, null, null, 0);
mediaDecoder.start();
ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = mediaDecoder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] decoderOutputBuffers = mediaDecoder.getOutputBuffers();


int width = 320, height = 240;
int bitRate = 125000, frameRate = 15;
int colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar;
int iFrameInterval = 75;

// Create video format for encoder.
MediaFormat mediaFormatForEncoder = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc",width,height);
mediaFormatForEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate) ;
mediaFormatForEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
mediaFormatForEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
mediaFormatForEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, iFrameInterval);

// Prepare and start Encoder.
MediaCodec mediaEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
mediaEncoder.configure(mediaFormatForEncoder, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mediaEncoder.start();
ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers = mediaEncoder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = mediaEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
```

I'm really stuck here. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The output of the encoder will be an elementary stream. Can you try decoding the same through JM Code (as your codec type is H.264) and view the YUV data?

Answer (score 0):

@Ganesh's comment is the correct hint.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html to mux your stream(s) to a proper container format, for example MP4.

Comment: This was added in API 18.